# invalid syntax in kill

Tags: bash, backup, kill

when trying to run these syntax in centos7:

```
kill -9 $(lsof | egrep '/nfs/backup' | awk '{print $2;}' | sort -fu)
```

i'm getting error:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Please advise what might have been a typo or mis-syntax.

Comment: Welcome to SO, are you sure you have put complete command in your post? Since error shows `kill` error but your sample shown command doesn't have it, please add correct command in your post and let me know then.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If you're piping that command to kill, you need to use `xargs`. `kill` doesn't get the list of PIDs from standard input, only from the arguments.

Comment: If you're doing `kill $(that command line)`, you'll get the error when there are no matches for `/nfs/backup`.

Comment: sorry i was miscopy the syntax before, yes it have a kill command in front of it.

Comment: @Barmar so if there are no matches, it's fine to have that error? Instead if there are any matches, it would instantly kill all process matching the pattern?

Comment: you need to learn how to debug such problems. This one is very easy. Just run `lsof | egrep '/nfs/backup' | awk '{print $2;}' | sort -fu` and see what you get. If it is empty, then as Barmar seys, there's nothing to kill. If you get a result back and you still get an error message then run `kill -9 <paste the result here>` . AND using `kill -9` as a first solution to killing  a process is not considered good practice. Search here for explanations. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mapfile -t process_ids <<<"$(lsof 2>/dev/null | egrep '/nfs/backup' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -fu)"  
kill -9 "${process_ids[@]}"
```

And `awk '{print $2;}'` gives you, for example 1234; but pid is 1234.
I think that `awk {print $2}` will be correctly

Comment: Won't this get the same error if `$process_ids` is an empty array?

Comment: `;` is a statement separator in `awk`. It's optional before `}`, but it won't be printed literally.

Comment: `[[ -n "${process_ids[*]}" ]] && kill -9 "${process_ids[@]}"`